# Collecting command history information from root and user profile

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I am writing a bash script to collect bash and shell command history information on a Mac OSX endpoint. I am running the script as root. This is just a part of a bigger script. The issue I am running into is that it only captures command history info for the root profile and gives me the same info for the current user profile too. I know I can just 'cat' all "_history" files and output them to a txt file but that does not give me timestamp which I really want in my output.

Any suggestions are welcome.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo *****************Shell Command history for Root**************** > Shell_History.txt

HISTFILE=~/.sh_history
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "

set -o history           
history >> Shell_History.txt

echo *****************Bash Command history for Root**************** > Bash_History.txt

HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "

set -o history           
history >> Bash_History.txt


echo *****************Command history for user $USER****************************** > User_History.txt
USER=`users`
HISTFILE=/Users/$USER/.bash_history
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
set -o history
history >> User_History.txt
```

Comment: Instead of setting `HISTFILE`, you can use `history filename` and it should display the contents of that file.

Comment: @Barmar Can you provide more context to your suggestion please.

Comment: `history /Users/$USER/.bash_history >> User_History.txt`